# Scheduler.elastic() creating only two threads, on what basis will it create threads, CPU Processors of VM?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a VM which has 2 CPU's.

***Here is the VM's CPU Info:***
CPU(s):                **2**;
On-line CPU(s) list:   **0,1**;
Thread(s) per core:    **1**

Running webflux **(which has ParallelFlux of 1000 Objects running on elastic() Scheduler)** application on it. it's always creating only 2 threads to execute the objects in flux.

tried using of **FromSchedular(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(500))**, still its creating 2 threads only.

**Do i need to increase CPU's on VM or is there any other solution?**

```
public Flux<FieldResult> execute(List<Field> fieldList){

        return Flux.fromIterable(fieldList)
                   .parallel()
                   .runOn(elastic())
                   .flatMap(field -> {
                      return processField(field);
                   });
}
```

Comment: Share some code as well, please.

Comment: `Schedulers.elastic()` uses an [*unbounded* amount of threads](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/scheduler/Schedulers.html#elastic--). (as oppose to `Schedulers.parallel()`, which, by default, will use a fixed pool the same size as the number of cores you have available.) There must be something else wrong with your code here; we'll need to see it to work out what.

Comment: figured it out, by default parallel() is using Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() to create no of threads. .parallel(fieldList.size()) solved my problem. thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [Flux.parallel()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#parallel--) creates as many rails as there are CPU cores by default.

To use more rails you need to use [Flux.parallel(int parallelism)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#parallel-int-). After that you can use `ParallelFlux.runOn(Schedulers.elastic())`.

In your example:

```
public ParallelFlux<FieldResult> execute(List<Field> fieldList){

    return Flux.fromIterable(fieldList)
               .parallel(fieldList.size())
               .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
               .map(field -> {
                  return processField(field);
               });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will create threads in accordance to number of subscribers. ElasticBounded()  is the preferred method.

And using elastic vill guarentee that each subscriber gets it’s own thread.